# Java custom annotation/decorator @Testing

Tags: java, android, annotations, decorator, compile-time

I want to do something like this:

@Testing

private void <strike>methodThatGivesWarningIfUserTriesToUseThis</strike>() {

}

where `@Testing` is a custom annotation/decorator in Java. I'd like the behaviour of this `@Testing` annotation to act ALMOST EXACTLY like the `@Deprecated` annotation - if i or someone else accidentally tries to use this in other parts of the code, the IDE will give a warning (and the method name also has a strike-through across the font). So for ex

how do i do this?

**note: i do not want to use `@Deprecated` because the method is not deprecated, i just want only to use it for testing purposes

**this marker should also be checked at compile time, not runTime.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that annotations are, as their name states, only for annotating :)
Creating such annotation is pretty easy, you need to do something like this:

```
public @interface Testing
```

In order for it to be used by your IDE at compile time you have to write a plug-in.

Here is a [good start](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html) I found in another SO question for starting with the plugin development.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're describing something like [`@VisibleForTesting`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.java), which is part of the [Guava libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (formerly known as "Google Collections"). If you do create one of your own, you'll probably want it to be [`@Documented` and `@Retention(SOURCE)`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Annotations/Meta-Annotations).

I'm not aware of any hook or feature that would cause non-`@Deprecated` members to trigger warnings or IDE flags as if they were `@Deprecated`. Because the Mirror API and Reflection API don't track individual expressions and statements (as documented [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373145/accessing-source-code-from-java-annotation-processor)), you probably won't have much luck detecting it yourself without a full Java parser.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider writing a [custom Lint rule](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules) to solve this problem. When your `@Testing` annotation is detected, the IDE would show a Lint warning (e.g., a yellow underline in the case of Eclipse+ADT).

A detailed guide to scanning Java source files for specific issues with Lint can be found in the Android Tools docs [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/writing-a-lint-check).