# Get method source code on annotation processor

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I have a class that is annotated with my annotation and then I want to get all the class fields and then check if their methods contain a call to a specific service.

The issue is that the method body is always null in this case.

Just a small note the classes of the fields live in another module.

```
public boolean process( Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv )
{
    Set<? extends Element> annotatedClasses = getAnnotatedClasses( annotations, roundEnv );
    
    annotatedClasses.forEach(annotatedClass -> {
        List<? extends Element> fields = getFields( annotatedClass );

        fields.forEach( field -> {
            List<ExecutableElement> methods = getMethods( field );

            methods.forEach( method -> {
                MethodScanner methodScanner = new MethodScanner();
                MethodTree methodTree = methodScanner.scan( method, this.trees );
                BlockTree body = methodTree.getBody();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `MethodScanner` class comes from here: [Accessing source code from Java Annotation Processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373145/accessing-source-code-from-java-annotation-processor)

Any way of getting the method source code?

Thanks

Comment: The compiler tree api, in the answers you are linking to, requires that the source for the methods in question are presently being compiled, otherwise the AST will not be available. This is probably what you are encountering.

Comment: It might be possible to open the class files of classes which are not currently compiled. You could analyze these class files with ASM instead of using the Compiler Tree API. However, ASM would not work on classes to be compiled, so you would have to maintain two separate branches, one for classes currently compiled, one for classes in other modules.