# How to import `java sun tools` as a normal gradle dependency?

Tags: java, gradle

I need to use `compiler tree api` in my custom annotation processor logic . the compiler tree api belongs to `sun tools.jar` . i was thinking it could be import as a simple normal gradle dependency like `import group: 'com.sun', name: 'tools', version: '1.8'` , But it's not working .

I've searched many tech blogs , it seems like the common solution is `compile file("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar")` , apparently it's lake of compatibility。 is there any better solution to solve this ？

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using Java 8? Because `tools.jar` no longer exists as of Java 9; its code was moved into JDK modules (e.g., [`jdk.compiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/jdk.compiler/module-summary.html)).

Comment: yes，i'm using  Java 8 .

Comment: Then my guess is what you've found is the best approach, though I've never personally had reason to depend on `tools.jar` when using Java 8. But I doubt it's a Maven artifact, as it's part of the implementation of a JDK. What you've found seems reasonable, at least for an application or sub-project library. I'm not sure how `file` dependencies work with external libraries (i.e., those published to and downloaded from a repository). You also have to be mindful of the fact that JREs typically don't include `tools.jar`.

Comment: My process logic only run at compile time , so JRE is not a problem .  it's quite reasonable because application won't  depends on jdk things usually . but sometimes it's the only way to get things done , ie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373145/accessing-source-code-from-java-annotation-processor  .